# Android count rows and show it in list view

Tags: android, join, simplecursoradapter

Hi i have a table category

```
|_id|name| 
|1  |cat1
|2  |cat2
|3  |cat3
|4  |cat4
```

and i have other table

```
  |_id|category_id|name
  | 1 |2          |name1
  | 1 |1          |name1
  | 1 |2          |name1
```

i want to count the category_id and show it in a listview

like

```
  cat1 (items 10)
```

but how to show this with a cursor and and adapter because you can only add one cursor to the adapter
is there a elegant solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use one sql statement, you won't have more than one cursor. Try something like this:

```
select c.name, count(*) 
  from category as c join other_table as o 
    on c._id = o.category_id 
  group by c.name;
```

Comment: yes thats perfect thanks
but how i can execute the query in a content provider since there s only a query method with single table possible thanks
is there any other was or just use rawQuery??

Comment: I don't know nothing about Content Providers